# Core Plot : Is a sliced (little split from the rest) like pie chart possible?

Tags: ios, core-plot

Am using core plot to draw graphs in an iOS App. can we draw such a pie chart (where the orange slice seems to be a bit away from the rest of the pie) with core plot?

[image]

Any help please?

Comment: Are you trying to make a Mr. T head??

Comment: google Mr. T pie chart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See here:

http://core-plot.googlecode.com/hg/documentation/html/iOS/protocol_c_p_t_pie_chart_data_source-p.html

radialOffsetForPieChart

Comment: Thanks, @Jim ; let me try & get back